# Returning values into a tuple?

Tags: python, python-3.x, sorting

Struggling trying to create a function def of how to return three accepted integers and  into a tuple in a sorted format from least to greatest depending if ascending is true. How would I go about coding this out? Would I use a for loop with if statements whether its ascending? I have a general idea for the sorting using "sorted(list)" and "sorted(list, reverse=True)."

Function code I have so far:

```
def sort3(x,y,z, ascending=True):
    list(x,y,z)
    return lst
```

Test should be like this sort3(5,3,4) returns (3,4,5)

Comment: `return tuple(sorted([x,y,z], reverse=(not ascending)))` You're just rewriting the `sorted` function though...

Comment: Actually he's returning `lst`, which is not defined.

Comment: @JohnGordon good catch.

Comment: @JohnGordon Noted.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should do the trick:

```
def sort3(x, y, z, ascending=True):
    return tuple(sorted([x, y, z], reverse=not ascending))
```

Comment: Thank you, very simplified. Guess I was over thinking it.

Answer (score 0):

Theoretically you could do this with a series of `if` statements, however Python has functions built-in that can perform this task for you much more simply.
Try using the `sorted()` function (which returns a *list* type object) in combination with the `tuple()` function, to convert that list to a *tuple*.

Answer (score 0):

```
def sort3(x, y, z):
    d = [x, y ,z]
    return tuple(sorted(d))
```

Isn't it enough?